# How to use the MOD operator in TRS-80 model 100 BASIC?

Tags: basic, trs-80-model-100

I'm finding the **MOD** operand is not working when I enter it in the BASIC prompt. This is how I write it out.

```
PRINT 1 * MOD(23)

?SN Error
```

I have looked into a reference guide and it is too broad on the MOD operand.
On page 10 in the link.

[TRS-80 Model 100 Reference](http://www.classiccmp.org/cini/pdf/Tandy/Model%20100%20Quick%20Reference.pdf)

Answer (score 11):

`MOD` is an operator, not a function.

Try `? 10 mod 9` and see yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Several BASIC dialects have `DIV` and `MOD` operators, which return the quotient and remainder respectively from integer division.  This is nearly equivalent to using `/` and `%` operators on integers in C.  They are infix operators, even though their syntax is a keyword rather than a symbol.

Conversely, the `/` operator in most BASICs performs floating-point division and has no remainder counterpart.

```
A = 124
D = 34
Q = A DIV D
R = A MOD D
F = A / D
PRINT Q,R,F
```

yields

```
3    22    3.6471
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone unfamiliar with mathematics the answer is simple.  After trying brute force I found that the format is sometimes confusingly different than pencil and paper.

Here it is.

```
print 124 MOD 34
22
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what did you think the meaning of a one-operand MOD function would be?

Comment: And why multiply it by one?

Comment: Mathematicians use "mod" more has a notation indicating they're working with the integers modulo N rather than an operator.  They'll write "5 = 12 mod 7" hence Travis' first guess.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic covers this in more detail